# Consuming Webhook payloads in Vue/Pinia in real time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, sockets, webhooks, square

So, i'm relatively new to Vue, and I'm currently using it to build a small app that displays order data from Square's API.

I'm currently working on a stack that uses rails to make api calls using the square.rb gem. The frontend is entirely Vue which uses Pinia as a store, and there isnt going to be any kind of database behind this because reasons.

All data is provided directly via Square's API. I am currently polling to update order info, but my client wants to make this app truly real time, as it deals with food deliveries through ride-share companies and the purpose of this app is to show in real time statuses of orders for an in house screen at the restaurant.

Now Square has a webhook subscription service, and based on my reading it sounds like I can consume these to update my app, but there are a few logical leaps that I havent been able to make yet with how to get that data to the frontend of my app.

My questions are the following, with the intent being to connect the dots between the different technologies I might need to employ here to make this work. Kinda get a sense of what i'd need and where to link it up.

1. Can I use vue to consume webhook payloads directly and update through reactivity? That would be ideal, but I have found no docs yet that give me a good idea of whether thats possible.
2. If that is not possible, do I need to use some sort of socket connection (socket.io) to listen for these webhook updates?
3. If the current setup or proposed setup in the questions above is not feasible, what is a better solution for handling this while still using Vue?

Comment: You're missing a way that a webhook works. Third-party service should do a request to a specific url of your web server (more specifically, app server). Vue app is not a server, so you still need one to achieve this. 1 Not directly tied to Vue and not needed to be explicitly documented, it's just browser JS app, as long as there's data to show on client side, you can do something with it - display it in a console or Vue view, doesn't matter 2. Yes, a webserver with a socket of some sort, receive POST request on webhook endpoint and send data through a socket to a client

Comment: Ok, so if I understand it right, I should set up a webhook to hit my rails controller endpoint with the update, and then set up a socket to listen to that rails controller for updates and when they come in, pipe that into my pinia store to update the current data, making good use of reactivity already in place to update the various parts of the data?

Comment: Yes, looks like that